# Spring Integration ImapFolder unpredictable short lifetime

Tags: spring-integration, jakarta-mail, imap

I have Imap idle based IntegrationFlow configured from following spec:

```
Mail.imapIdleAdapter(url)
                .javaMailProperties(javaMailProperties)
                .javaMailAuthenticator(new Authenticator() {
                    @Override
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                })
                .shouldMarkMessagesAsRead(false)
                .autoCloseFolder(false)
                .shouldDeleteMessages(false)
                .transactionSynchronizationFactory(transactionSynchronizationFactory())
                .transactional(transactionInterceptor());
```

I want pseudo-transaction mechanism to mark messages as SEEN after succesful handling(i.e. commit), but the problem is that annoying FolderClosedException always pops up while evaluating my SPEL from bean :

```
@Bean
public TransactionSynchronizationFactory transactionSynchronizationFactory() {
    ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor processor =
        new ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor();

SpelExpressionParser spelParser = new SpelExpressionParser();

processor.setAfterCommitExpression(
    spelParser.parseExpression(
        "getPayload().setFlag(T(javax.mail.Flags$Flag).SEEN, true)"));
return new DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory(processor);
}
```

I have a following logic for openinng folder in handle method before working with email content:

```
public MimeMessageParser parse(MimeMessage mimeMessage) {
    Folder folder = mimeMessage.getFolder();
    try (folder) {
        if (!folder.isOpen()) {
            folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
        }
        return new MimeMessageParser(mimeMessage).parse();
    }
}
```

Is there any mistakes I have done or it's just my email provider is too greedy with its connections? P.S.: while debugging I noticed that sometimes FolderClosedException or "This operation is not allowed on an open folder" pops up, because in rare cases two consequent isOpen calls may give different results. Just in case there is not multithreading load at all. Workaround here is to use @Retryable mechanism but seems like a code smell, also I should still give up pseudo transactions here.

Comment: I think there is still some multi-threading in your app. Hard to say what is going on without the whole project to play with. Also consider to upgrade to the latest Spring Integration. There was a change around executor and so: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/whats-new.html#x6.1-mail

Comment: thank you for the attention, should do some deep research I think before spending your time! May I ask you is there any built-in solution in your framework to deal with all unread messages while instanting Flow from ImapIdleChannelAdapter or there only way is to manually fetch and handle all messages before flow registration? Sorry for question in comment, not sure it worth new question

Comment: I think it really deserves a new question since the context of it is not clear for me. Why would one do a manual fetch when `ImapIdleChannelAdapter` does that for us just after its start? Plus: why do one need a manual flow registration for this logic? It is probably possible to do that manually some how via Mail API, but that's already out of Spring Integration scope.